# sprite kit getting nil value on collision

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

when I check for collision in my sprite kit game I'm getting a nil value when 1 node is colliding with 2 other nodes simultaneously. Basically I have some 'monsters' and a 'fireball', sometimes 2 monsters are in the same location, and the fireball that I shoot from my player is colliding with both monsters at the same time, so collision is being detected twice simultaneously it seems like.

The collision method is running twice in a row, but the problem is the first time it runs, I'm removing the fireball from the scene, so the second collision is getting a "nil" for the fireball, or so it seems like it.

heres the code:

```
    func projectileDidCollideWithMonster(projectile:SKNode, monster:SKNode) {
        println("Hit")

        (monster as Character).negativeEffect.runningSpeed = (projectile as FireBall).negativeEffect.getRunningSpeed()
        projectile.removeFromParent()
        println("finished hit")
    }

    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

        // 1
        var firstBody: SKPhysicsBody
        var secondBody: SKPhysicsBody
        if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
            firstBody = contact.bodyA
            secondBody = contact.bodyB
        } else {
            firstBody = contact.bodyB
            secondBody = contact.bodyA
        }

        // 2
        if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.Monster != 0) &&
            (secondBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.Projectile != 0)) {
                projectileDidCollideWithMonster(secondBody.node!, monster: firstBody.node!)
        }

    }
```

any idea on how to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

doing some research and thinking, I came up with the following fix for now, until I find a better fix (if one exists)

first I made first/second body optionals, then I will check if they're nil before unwrapping them:

```
var firstBody: SKPhysicsBody?
var secondBody: SKPhysicsBody?

if (firstBody!.node! != nil && secondBody!.node! != nil) {
       if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.Monster != 0) &&
                (secondBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.Projectile != 0)) {
                projectileDidCollideWithMonster(secondBody.node!, monster: firstBody.node!)
        }
}
```